# Node.js and sqlite: synchronized in callback

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to code the following logic:

```
if account in the DB,
  then update fields
  else insert new row with data.
```

This is an atomic operation, so I do it as SQL transaction (DB is sqlite3):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT rowid FROM Account WHERE email=?;
-- Depending on SELECT's result, run INSERT or UPDATE:
INSERT INTO Accounts(email, name, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
UPDATE Accounts SET name=? phone=? WHERE rowid=?;
COMMIT;
```

I make a decision to run `insert` or `update` in the callback of `select`. But to the moment SQL statement are no longer synchronized! In between synchronized block end and callback execution, arbitrary SQL statements can be executed.

```
db.synchronized(function() {
  db.run('BEGIN;');
  db.get('SELECT ...;', [...], function(err, row) {
    // Before this callback is getting executed, there are no sync!
    // Assume no errors
    function commit() {
      // Before this callback is getting executed, there are no sync too!
      db.run('COMMIT;');
      // Use this.lastID
    }
    if (row) {
      db.run('INSERT ...', [...], commit);
    } else {
      db.run('UPDATE ...', [...], commit);
    }
  });
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async)?

Comment: Do you suggest using `series`? I have the same here! but the thing is that between steps of the series, steps of another series may happen! The order is right. But I can't have series mixed.

Comment: oh, I see, so you need it to be completely synchronous? In that case, then yes - I'd say series is the way to go, that way one will wait for the callback of the other.